How to set up correct cell number format for culture on DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Hi ALL! I have a problem with OpenXml, i have to generate a report and the  cells of the report must be number values so the end users make some calculations, but i cant make it work with the comma as decimal separator, this is the code im using DocumentFormat.OpenXml v2.16.0
Numbering Format
NumberingFormats numberingFormats = new NumberingFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
NumberingFormat decimalFormat = new NumberingFormat()
{ 
    NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)165U,
    FormatCode = "#,##0.000" 
};
numberingFormats.Append(decimalFormat);

Cell Formats
CellFormats cellFormats1 = new CellFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
CellFormat cellFormat5 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)165U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)1U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)2U, ApplyBorder = true, ApplyNumberFormat = true };
cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat5);

Create Cell Function
private Cell CreateCell(decimal value, uint styleIndex, CellValues dataType )
{
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;
    cell.DataType = dataType;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString("#,##0.000", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES")));
    return cell;
}

I try to set the cell value as string, an the number formats shows Ok but for example Sum function returns 0, if i set the value to the cell as decimal the coma decimal separator is not applied.
Sum Function Example

If someone need it there is a class that can be append on the Workbook, the class name is ServerFormat, in this class you can specify the culture, it doesnt work on all excel like programs
    private void GenerateWorkbookPartContent(WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        ServerFormat serverFormat = new ServerFormat() { Culture = "es-ES" };
        Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
        Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet() { Name = "Sheet1", SheetId = (UInt32Value)1U, Id = "rId1" };
        sheets.Append(sheet1);
        workbook.Append(sheets);
        workbook.Append(serverFormat);
        workbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
    }

Then just save the cell value with data type number
